# adding new value each time in my sql in same column without delelting ols one

Tags: mysql

I am new to My sql" i want add data or string from text box in my sql from php in 1 column on same id means each time a string is entered in a txt single column gets updated by adding new name

Answer (score 0):

If I may attempt to translate your request: you have users on your site that enters data in a text box and clicks Submit. You want to keep that data, by user. Later the same user can enter different data in the same text box and Submit again. You want to keep that data, but don't want to overwrite the previous data.

If that's what you're asking for, the solution is simple. You have the id of the user and the id of the type of data entered (Name, AcctNum, whatever). You also have the timestamp of when they pressed Submit. Incorporate that value as part of the record. So you keep everything they entered and when they entered it. The timestamp becomes part of the key of the record so helps make it unique, but also gives you a meaningful value to sort the entries on.

Comment: Hi Thank you tomm for you reply let me explain bit further
----------
id    values
1     string1,string2,string3.
now if i use update command what happens is it deletes the old values which is dont want instead i want to add multiple colmn values under same id. one at a time  without deleting old ones.I hope i made it clear
i am using My sql and PHP
means i have a php form with a text box and i want whenever a user types something in that text box i gett added to values column but under same id.

Comment: Then the answer is the same: id, timestamp, string1, string2, string3. If the timestamp is defined with ID as the key, then you can have multiple entries with the same ID, as long as the timestamp value is different. And I don't think any human can click a button fast enough to get both in the same clock tick. So instead of updating old data, just write a new version. Details on one way of doing it is documented here: http://www.slideshare.net/TommCarr/bitemporal-rdbms-2014 I'm not sure if you want all that functionality or just a simple history of data changes, but there it is.